# 2D Game Physics: How to evaluate when an accelerating ray is close to a point?

Tags: 2d, physics

Given a ray in a 2D world at position **p** with initial velocity **u** and acceleration **a** how can I tell when it's within a certain distance **r** from a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform motion: s = ut + at^2/2

Or p(t) - p(0) = ut + at^2 / 2

You want the first t >= 0 for which (p(t) - C).(p(t) - C) = r^2.

If u and a could be non-perpendicular then I think you have to solve a quartic.

Comment: Thanks, yes the directions are arbitrary. I was fearing a quartic as I'm unfamiliar in solving them, but is it just a case of running the constants through some published quartic solution and using the least positive amount?

Comment: @Nick, I think it should be, yes, although there's no guarantee of a numerically stable solution - see http://www-staff.it.uts.edu.au/~don/pubs/solving.html